# Fatal: Error in configuration file (dovecot)

Tags: dovecot, letsencrypt

I am getting an error that I don't understand well. It says it is missing one opening bracket on line 33. Unfortunately I have tried at the beginning of the line and at the end of the line. Finally the program keeps giving this error. First, I paste the code then I paste systemctl :

```
##
## ManageSieve specific settings
##

# Uncomment to enable managesieve protocol:
#protocols = $protocols sieve

# Service definitions

  #inet_listener sieve_deprecated {
  # port = 2000
  #}

service managesieve-login {
inet_listener sieve {
    port = 4190
}
}

  # Number of connections to handle before starting a new process. Typically
  # the only useful values are 0 (unlimited) or 1. 1 is more secure, but 0
  # is faster. <doc/wiki/LoginProcess.txt>
  #service_count = 1

  # Number of processes to always keep waiting for more connections.
  #process_min_avail = 0

  # If you set service_count=0, you probably need to grow this.
  #vsz_limit = 64M
#}

service managesieve {
  Max. number of ManageSieve processes (connections)
  process_limit = 1024
}
```

```
    sudo systemctl status dovecot
    × dovecot.service - Dovecot IMAP/POP3 email server
         Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/dovecot.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
         Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Mon 2022-08-22 22:28:03 CEST; 8min ago
           Docs: man:dovecot(1)
                 https://doc.dovecot.org/
        Process: 111106 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/dovecot -F (code=exited, status=89)
       Main PID: 111106 (code=exited, status=89)
            CPU: 28ms
    
    août 22 22:28:03 Ubuntu-ThinkPad-X250 systemd[1]: Starting Dovecot IMAP/POP3 email server...
    août 22 22:28:03 Ubuntu-ThinkPad-X250 dovecot[111107]: doveconf: Fatal: Error in configuration file /etc/dovecot/conf.d/20-managesieve.conf line 33: Expecting '{'
    août 22 22:28:03 Ubuntu-ThinkPad-X250 dovecot[111106]: doveconf: Error: managesieve-login: dump-capability process returned 89
    août 22 22:28:03 Ubuntu-ThinkPad-X250 dovecot[111106]: doveconf: Fatal: Error in configuration file /etc/dovecot/conf.d/10-ssl.conf line 12: ssl_cert: Can't open file /etc/letsencrypt/live/mail.example.com/fullchain.pem: No such file or directory
    août 22 22:28:03 Ubuntu-ThinkPad-X250 systemd[1]: dovecot.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=89/n/a
    août 22 22:28:03 Ubuntu-ThinkPad-X250 systemd[1]: dovecot.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
    août 22 22:28:03 Ubuntu-ThinkPad-X250 systemd[1]: Failed to start Dovecot IMAP/POP3 email server.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like line 33 should be commented out - it is not a procedural statement. Add a `#` before it.